# Why is the notification sent from firebase is getting delay in receiving

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, delay

**Below is the code for listening notification in flutter i am sending a notification from firebase console**

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: 'ic_launcher',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly explain it in details what is the actual problem you cannot receive notification when the app is open then you have to use local notification plugin for notification to be shown on app when app is open

Comment: i am able to receive the notification but if i schedule it now and send it will be received with some delay at mobile side. Actual scenario is i am composing a notification from FCM console selecting now for schedule and sending but its coming late by >2min

Comment: i think it will be your internet connection i try the same but i did not get any delay